# txtbox decimal en C#

Tags: c#, windows-forms

estoy realizando un programa en c#, y tengo un problema que no se como poder solucionarlo.
Tengo un campo en la tabla clientes que es decimal. tengo la conexion realizada, uso store procedure desde la base de datos.

```
    public string Create()
    {
        DB.AddParameter("_nombre", this.nombre);
        DB.AddParameter("_telefono", this.telefono);
        DB.AddParameter("_credito", SqlDbType.Decimal).ToString();
        DB.AddParameter("_direccion", this.direccion);
        DB.AddParameter("_email", this.email);


        int res = DB.CRUD("sp_clientes_create");

        if (res == 1)
        {
            response = $"{App.ClsCommon.RowCreated}{Entity}";
        }
        else
        {
            response = $"{App.ClsCommon.NoRowAdded}{Entity}"; 
        }

        return response;

    }
```

En el formulario:

```
       private void Create()
    {
        client.Id = this.Id;
        client.Nombre = this.txtnombre.Text.Trim();
        client.Telefono = this.txttelefono.Text.Trim();
        client.Email = this.txtemail.Text.Trim();
        client.Direccion = this.txtdireccion.Text.Trim();
        client.Credito = this.txtcredit.Text.Trim(); 
        ClsUtils.Box(this.Id > 0 ? client.update() : client.Create());
        this.ResetUI(1);
        this.Data();

    }
```

En la linea

> Client.Credit = this.txtcredit.Text.Trim()

Me sale el siguiente mensaje de error el que no me permite ejecutar correctamente el formulario:

> No se puede convertir implicitamente el tipo 'string' en 'decimal'

El trabajo lo estoy realizando en C#, para finalizar el modulo cliente que estoy realizando me falta solucionar este pequeño inconveniente.

Desde ya muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta eso.

```
private void Create()
    {
        client.Id = this.Id;
        client.Nombre = this.txtnombre.Text.Trim();
        client.Telefono = this.txttelefono.Text.Trim();
        client.Email = this.txtemail.Text.Trim();
        client.Direccion = this.txtdireccion.Text.Trim();
        client.Credito = Decimal.Parse(this.txtcredit.Text.Trim()); 
        ClsUtils.Box(this.Id > 0 ? client.update() : client.Create());
        this.ResetUI(1);
        this.Data();
    }
```